# AWS account Id in SNS topic event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Is there any way to get AWS Account Id in an SNS topic event to the subscriber? Actually, in my case, I want multiple customer account can trigger their s3 putObject to the given sns topic arn which is from my account and I have a lambda method which is subscribed to that topic. Now I'm getting event payload in my lambda handler whenever a customer puts an object to s3 bucket. But as I said, there would be many customer so my lambda need to process that coming event is from which customer? So I need customer account Id available in the sns event payload, is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is confusing. Could you please Edit your question, and explain exactly which entities (SNS, Lambda, publisher) are in which Account, and also describe the complete end-to-end flow you are seeking. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein updated my question please have a read

Answer (score 0):

Schema that is received by subscriber already contains Arns of both subscriber and topic. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns.html) is the schema. We can parse the accountId from it.

```
    `"TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:sns-lambda"`
```

`"EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:sns-lambda:21be56ed-a058-49f5-8c98-aedd2564c486"`

Comment: Yeah true but this topic is in an account where the lambda is present and the publisher is from different account. Lambda wants the publisher's account id

Comment: sorry, I mis-read your question. Typical design would be have an individual topic in source account and Lambda subscribe cross account to all the topics, to avoid latency issues when source account is writing to SNS. Let me think if there is a solution

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your situation is:

- Multiple AWS Accounts have Amazon S3 buckets with an Amazon S3 Event configured to trigger your AWS Lambda function
- You want the ability to for the Lambda function to detect which account triggered the event

I don't think that this information is available. Here is a sample S3 Put event from the AWS Lambda "Test" console:

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "ap-southeast-2",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "example-bucket",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test/key",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There does not appear to be a field containing the Account ID of the source bucket.

To confirm this, I triggered an event on an S3 bucket and logged the event. I could not find any reference to an AWS Account ID.

Comment: But aws EventBridge provides account Id in the event bus event, i thought some how doable with sns topic

Comment: It does not seem to make it to the Lambda `event`, but feel free to show an example if you are receiving this information.